# Get Pagination after filter on collection Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel query builder to get data. Once I received data I put some filters to get relevant data, But after getting relevant data I lost default pagination. Any solution to come up against this problem ? Thanks in advance.
My Code is

```
        $tests = DB::table('view_tests')->whereIn('metric_id',$metricsIds)->paginate(4);

        $tests = $tests->filter(function ($item) use ($var) {
                    return false !== stristr($item->name, $var) || 
                    false !== stristr($item->section_name, $var) || 
                    false !== stristr($item->method, $var) || 
                    false !== stristr($item->limit, $var) || 
                    false !== stristr($item->accredited_detail, $var);

               return view('frontend.test_detailes',compact('tests'))->render();
```

And on View am using

```
              {{ $tests->links() }}
```

Erro : Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist.

Comment: Your filter function does not seem complete? Regarding your question: I would advise using the filters on the query builder, instead of filtering after paginating. If you do not want to do that, you can manually create a [paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)

Comment: can you please tell me any example of this?

Comment: You can simply use a `where()` clause. The [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) explains this better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: I want to filter only that record which I will get from the metric_id check.

Comment: That is fine, with the query builder you can `chain` functions. So if you `chain` an additional `where()` function **after** the `whereIn()` functions, both constraints are used to retrieve your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase performance, consider moving your filtering to the query builder instead of on the paginated results. This will also solve your problem regarding paginating. there are two options here:

**Use the query builder (preferred)**

The filters you have used in your example can be used on the query builder instead, as follows:

```
$tests = DB::table('view_tests')
    ->whereIn('metric_id',$metricsIds)
    ->where('name', '=', $var)
    ->paginate(4);
```

You can chain multiple constraints here. Please consult the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)

**Manually creating a paginator**

Another option, which I would not advise, is to manually create a [paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator). So change the `->paginate(4);` and create the paginator **after** filtering.